# hilighting specific text in datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, richtextbox

to highlight search term in datagridview entered from textbox 
i have added datagridviewrichtextbox custom column in datagridview
from this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView

my datagridview is in readonly mode, and i dont know what to do further:
1. do i need to find richtextbox control in datagridview and call find method, then color the seelction.
2. i have to change custom column project.

need help!!

Comment: i have zero understanding of what you've wrote, and so does the rest 8 people that entered your question

Comment: i have added the dattagridview richtextbox custom column type in my vb winapp, downloaded from above mentioned link ,and populated data in my dgv, but it is not highlighting the search term, sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: i suggest you close this question and open a new one, use tags of vb.net and datagridview, show you code and make sure you know how a question should look like. you won't get attention at this question anymore, so delete it